# When are errors written to SSISDB?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

In my master-package in the **On Error** eventhandler a child-package *Logging* is fired.
This package fires his/her own child-package: *SendMail*.
*Sendmail* executes a query against the SSISDB. This query collects all errors having the latest execution_id. The results are written to a flatfile.
The flatfile is then attached to an email and sent to me.

However, if I run this in SSDT this works beautifully. When running this on the server the file is empty. The query is looking for errors resulting in the latest execution. However, if I change the query so it looks for an older execution, everything runs fine.
It looks like the errors are not written to the database yet at the time I am trying to collect them. However, simply making the query wait for 5 seconds does not mean I get results.

Can I somehow make sure the errors have been written to the SSISDB the moment I need them?

This is the query I use to extract the errors from the SSISDB. When I change  `(SELECT MAX(execution_id) FROM SSISDB.catalog.executions)` to the previous execution_id with errors everything works. (But I see the errors of the previous run)

```
SELECT distinct
            cast(message_time as datetime2) as message_time
            ,cast(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(messaGE, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ... '), 
             CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), ' ... '), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ... ') as nvarchar(400)) AS MESSAGE
            ,cast(execution_path as nvarchar(400)) as execution_path
    FROM   (
           SELECT  em.*
           FROM    catalog.event_messages em
           WHERE   em.operation_id = (SELECT MAX(execution_id) FROM SSISDB.catalog.executions)
               AND event_name NOT LIKE '%Validate%'
           )q
    WHERE   event_name = 'OnError'
```

Comment: What is the "Server-wide Default Logging Level" set to on SSISDB and what was the logging level when you executed the package?

Comment: 'Server-wide Default Logging level' is set to Performance. In SSDT this  is set to 'basic'. Setting 'Server-wide Default Logging level' to 'Basic does not provide a solution.

Comment: When you executed the package what was this set as, i.e. the "LOGGING_LEVEL" @parameter_name parameter if you used T-SQL?

Comment: @command=N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\AnalyzIT\AnalyzIT\00-Master.dtsx\"" /SERVER "\".\"" /ENVREFERENCE 4 /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'